# Is it possible in Python to write a sort of truth table to simplify the writing of if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, truthtable

Let's say I'm trying to print out the orientation of a tablet device using its accelerometer that provides acceleration measurements in the horizontal and vertical directions of the display of the device. I know that such a printout could be done using a set of `if` statements in a form such as the following:

```
if abs(stableAcceleration[0]) > abs(stableAcceleration[1]) and stableAcceleration[0] > 0:
    print("right")
elif abs(stableAcceleration[0]) > abs(stableAcceleration[1]) and stableAcceleration[0] < 0:
    print("left")
elif abs(stableAcceleration[0]) < abs(stableAcceleration[1]) and stableAcceleration[1] > 0:
    print("inverted")
elif abs(stableAcceleration[0]) < abs(stableAcceleration[1]) and stableAcceleration[1] < 0:
    print("normal")
```

Would it be possible to codify the logic of this in some neater form? Could a sort of truth table be constructed such that the orientation is simply a lookup value of this table? What would be a good way to do something like this?

---

EDIT: Following [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947006/is-it-possible-in-python-to-write-a-sort-of-truth-table-to-simplify-the-writing#comment48015237_29947006) by @jonrsharpe, I have implemented the logic in a way like the following:

```
tableOrientations = {
    (True,  True):  "right",
    (True,  False): "left",
    (False, True):  "inverted",
    (False, False): "normal"
}
print(
    tableOrientations[(
        abs(stableAcceleration[0]) > abs(stableAcceleration[1]),
        stableAcceleration[0] > 0
    )]
)
```

Comment: You are missing the cases for `abs(stableAcceleration[0]) == abs(stableAcceleration[1])` and `stableAcceleration[0] == 0`. But I'd suggest just defining two shorter names for `stableAcceleration[0]` and `stableAcceleration[1]` and leaving the rest as-is.

Comment: You could have a dictionary where the key is a tuple of booleans (e.g. `(True, False)`) or integers (e.g. `(-1, 0)`) and the value is the appropriate string (e.g. `'right'`).

Comment: This might be extreme overengineering in your case, but I had a similar problem with very complex if statements detailing dozens of different rules, and I solved it by creating a decision tree with the scikit-learn toolkit.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for your comment. In the case you mentioned, I think it's just a case of taking no action.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your suggestion. I think I'll go with your approach. The combination of the tuple of booleans in a dictionary is close to the concept of a truth table.

Comment: @Pedro Werneck Thank you for your comment. Indeed, for any complex set of rules a decision tree or a learning algorithm otherwise can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing something along the lines of this:

```
x = 0;
if abs(stableAcceleration[0]) > abs(stableAcceleration[1]) :
    x += 2
if stableAcceleration[0] > 0:
    x +=1

list = ["normal", "invert", "left", "right"]

print(list[x])
```

That being said, your series of `if` statements don't cover every case.

Comment: This treats the `==` cases differently. OP seems to just ignore those.

Comment: Thank you for that clever solution. With each condition, you change the index moving closer to the answer.

Comment: @tobias_k We could increment every thing by 1 more and add one more check. Then have `list = ["", "normal", "invert", "left", "right"]`. Then it'll print nothing for all the remaining cases.